# Only showing results that are the same from 2 queries

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 1 **(one)** table contains a list of games. For example:

1st row: `team1 = abc; team2 = xyz;`

2nd row: `team1 = xyz; team2 = abc;`

3rd row: `team1 = asd; team2 = jkl;`

I've got about 4,000 rows like this.
2 teams may have played each other many times. Each row is a separate game.

A user enters a `team1` name and a `team2` name and I basically want to display all rows that match that. So basically all games that have those 2 teams playing.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE team1 = '$team1' OR team1 = '$team2'
UNION
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE team2 ='$team2' OR team2 = '$team1'
```

I've tried a few more things using an `INNER JOIN` but it didn't seem to work either.

Pretty new to SQL so any help would be appreciated!
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would return any game in which either `$team1` or `$team2` has played. From your question I understand that you really want any game where `$team1` played against `$team2`, so I'd try

```
SELECT * FROM matches 
WHERE 
   (team1 = '$team1' AND team2 = '$team2') OR 
   (team1 = '$team2' AND team2 = '$team1')
```

While you *could* also achive the same result using a `union`, it will be easier to understand and probably also quicker to do it this way, given you have an index on both columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with logical operators:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   matches 
WHERE  (team1 = '$team1' AND team2 = '$team2') OR
       (team1 = '$team2' AND team1 = '$team2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE team1 = '$team1' AND team2 = '$team2'
UNION
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE team1 ='$team2' AND team2 = '$team1'
```

Or you could do specify both arguments in the WHERE-clause to eliminate the use of UNION.

Answer (score 0):

If it can be either team in either place, you can just OR them all:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   matches 
WHERE  team1 = '$team1' OR team2 = '$team1' OR
       team1 = '$team2' OR team2 = '$team2'
```

But as others have mentioned, you probably only want the rows that have both team1 and team2 playing each other (in either combination). In which case - @Mureinik got the answer in before me.

Answer (score 0):

use UNION ALL that in place of UNION. That's it.

Comment: Erm, `UNION ALL` simply makes sure that *all* rows are in the result set, not just the distinct ones. How's that going to help?